# Add new row to a DataFrame based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame (I'm sorry for posting an image but I dont know how to write tables with more than 2 columns here on Stackoverflow lol)

[image]

It is missing the fifth month as you can see.

How can I detect and add a new row that contains the fifth month to get a new DataFrame with all months?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'YEAR1': [2020]*11, 'YEAR2': [2019]*11, 'MONTH': [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: is this your actual use-case? i ask because it feels a little hard to know which of the different ways this could be done without knowing specifically the situation? Should we compare the values in the month column against the list of 1-12? or something more? and do the columns YEAR1 and YEAR2 always just have a single value repeated?

Comment: Well, in the real case the missing MONTH value could be any number between 1-12. And the YEAR1 and the YEAR2 are pairs of years, with YEAR1 between 2016-2022 and YEAR2 between 2001 and 2022; Every pair of years  must have all 12 months.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is a model question meant to get an answer for a harder one. This wouldn't be the most wieldly answer in all use-cases, but for what you described, a simple

```
if 5 not in df['MONTH'].values:
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = [2020, 2021, 5]
```

would suffice.

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to solve a harder problem. As I commented above, in the real case the missing MONTH value could be any number between 1-12. And the YEAR1 and the YEAR2 are pairs of years, with YEAR1 between 2016-2022 and YEAR2 between 2001 and 2022; Every pair of years must have all 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[len(df.index)] = [2020, 2019, 5]
df.sort_values(by="MONTH", inplace=True)
```